# How to detect change in last 2 months starting from specific row in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have a dataframe like this:

```
Id  Policy_id   Start_Date  End_Date    Fee1    Fee2    Last_dup
0   b123        2019/02/24  2019/03/23  0       23      0
1   b123        2019/03/24  2019/04/23  0       23      0
2   b123        2019/04/24  2019/05/23  10      23      1
3   c123        2018/09/01  2019/09/30  10      0       0
4   c123        2018/10/01  2019/10/31  10      0       1
5   d123        2017/02/24  2019/03/23  0       0       0
6   d123        2017/03/24  2019/04/23  0       0       1
```

The column `Last_dup` is the result of applying `.duplicated` ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55608298/how-to-flag-last-duplicate-element-in-a-pandas-dataframe)).

The result of substraction of `End_Date` and `Start_Date` in this case is always *30* days for simplification. My goal is to detect change of `Fee1` and `Fee2` in the last 2 months for each `Policy_id`.

So first, I want to locate the last element of `Policy_id` then go up from the last element and compare the fees between months and detect change.

The expected result:

```
Id  Policy_id   Start_Date  End_Date    Fee1    Fee2    Last_dup    Changed
0   b123        2019/02/24  2019/03/23  0       23      0           0
1   b123        2019/03/24  2019/04/23  0       23      0           0
2   b123        2019/04/24  2019/05/23  10      23      1           1
3   c123        2018/09/01  2019/09/30  10      0       0           0
4   c123        2018/10/01  2019/10/31  10      0       1           0
5   d123        2017/02/24  2019/03/23  0       0       0           0
6   d123        2017/03/24  2019/04/23  0       0       1           0
```

I need to start for the specific row where `Last_dup` is `1` then go up and compare change of `FeeX`. Thanks!

Comment: So what does your expected output look like? Filtered DataFrame? New flag column?

Comment: I expect to get either unique rows of `Policy_id` with a column telling if there is change in last 2 months or not... or just add new flag column in all rows. Thanks man!

Comment: Please Sir, give me guidance as I will search for different pieces of the puzzle to solve this. I think I will need groupby, iloc and some index work...

Comment: If you want to look back 2 months, then should `Changed` be `1` only at `Id==2`?

Comment: I updated the question again... please help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding a "transaction number column" for each policy will make this easier. Then you can just de-dupe the transactions to see if there are "changed" rows.

Look at the following for example:

```
import pandas as pd

dat = [['b123', 234, 522], ['b123', 234, 522], ['c123', 34, 23], 
['c123', 38, 23], ['c123', 34, 23]]

cols = ['Policy_id', 'Fee1', 'Fee2']

df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=cols)

df['transaction_id'] = 1
df['transaction_id'] = df.groupby('Policy_id').cumsum()['transaction_id']

df2 = df[cols].drop_duplicates()

final_df = df2.join(df[['transaction_id']])
```

The output is:

```
      Policy_id  Fee1  Fee2  transaction_id
0      b123   234   522               1
2      c123    34    23               1
3      c123    38    23               2
```

And since `b123` only has one transaction after de-duping, you know that nothing changed. Something had to change with `c123`.

You can get all the changed transactions with `final_df[final_df.transaction_id > 1]`.

As mentioned, you might have to do some other math with the dates, but this should get you most of the way there.

**Edit:** If you want to only look at the last two months, you can filter the DataFrame prior to running the above.

How to do this:

Make a variable for your filtered date like so:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
filtered_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=60)
```

Then I would use the `pyjanitor` package to use its filter_date method. Just filter on whatever column is the column that you want; I thought that `Start_date` appears most reasonable.

```
import janitor

final_df.filter_date("Start_date", start=filtered_date)
```

Once you run `import janitor`, `final_df` will magically have the `filter_date` method available.

You can see more `filter_date` examples [here](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor/blob/dev/examples/filter_date.md).

Comment: I will accept this as answer since no one answered better solution; thanks!