# How to flag last duplicate element in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

As you know there is the method `.duplicated` to find duplicates in a column but what I need is the last duplicated element knowing that my data is ordered by Date.

Here is the expected result `Last_dup` for the column `Policy_id`:

```
Id  Policy_id   Start_Date  Last_dup
0   b123        2019/02/24  0
1   b123        2019/03/24  0
2   b123        2019/04/24  1
3   c123        2018/09/01  0
4   c123        2018/10/01  1
5   d123        2017/02/24  0
6   d123        2017/03/24  1
```

Thanks in advance for your help and support!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you look up the documentation for `duplicated()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) or [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with specify column and parameter `keep='last'` and then convert inverted mask to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Last_dup1'] = (~df['Policy_id'].duplicated(keep='last')).astype(int)
df['Last_dup1'] = np.where(df['Policy_id'].duplicated(keep='last'), 0, 1)
```

Or:

```
df['Last_dup1'] = (~df.duplicated(subset=['Policy_id'], keep='last')).astype(int)
df['Last_dup1'] = np.where(df.duplicated(subset=['Policy_id'], keep='last'), 0, 1)
```

---

```
print (df)
   Id Policy_id  Start_Date  Last_dup  Last_dup1
0   0      b123  2019/02/24         0          0
1   1      b123  2019/03/24         0          0
2   2      b123  2019/04/24         1          1
3   3      c123  2018/09/01         0          0
4   4      c123  2018/10/01         1          1
5   5      d123  2017/02/24         0          0
6   6      d123  2017/03/24         1          1
```

Comment: @SabiriS. - You are welcome, especially for nice data sample.

Comment: Please can you help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596750/how-to-detect-change-in-last-2-months-starting-from-specific-row-in-pandas-dataf) your answer helped me get a better view.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in below-mentioned way also (without using [Series.duplicated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html)) :

```
dictionary = df[['Id','Policy_id']].set_index('Policy_id').to_dict()['Id']
#here the dictionary values contains the most recent Id's
df['Last_dup'] = df.Id.apply(lambda x: 1 if x in list(dictionary.values()) else 0)
```